# Extjs chart zoom out

Tags: javascript, extjs4.2

I am kinda new to Extjs, and I am searching for a way to zoom out from a chart. I have found the way to zoom in by adding a listener:

```
listeners: {
        select: {
            fn: function(me, selection) {
                me.setZoom(selection);
                me.mask.hide();
            }
        }
}
```

but now, I want to reset the zoom and view the whole chart - and I can't find how to do that. I don't care having a special button for that..
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution... Need to use the function: restoreZoom()